# Shareds Behavior Jasmine + Protractor

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, specifications

I'm new with Protractor and jasmine framework to test an AngularJS Application.

I whould like to reuse some of my scenarios, like Login feature can call in all scenarios of my suite.
This is my login_test.js

```html
module.exports = function(testName, testFn) {

  const loginPage = pages.login;
  const mainPage = pages.main;
  var protractor;
  describe('common Login suite', function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    beforeEach(function() {

    });

    afterAll(function() {
      browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    });

    it(testName, function() {
      browser.get('http://localhost:9000/');
      loginPage.typeUserName('bxxxxx');
      loginPage.typePassword('xxxxxx');
      loginPage.clickLogin();
    });
  });

}
```

And here I have the remote_terminal feature, here I need call Login feature to perfom login in my scenario.

```js
var loginSuite = require('./login_test.js');

loginSuite('login Suite terminal feature', function(browser) {
  describe('description', function() {
    console.log('describe');
    it('it', function() {
      console.log('it');
    });
  });
});
```

But when this spec (remote_terminal) is called to run I got this message on my console

Started
Spec started
.
  common Login suite
    ✓ login Suite terminal feature

As you can see the describe and IT in the remote_terminal spec aren't ran.

Demo:
http://pavelbogomolenko.github.io/dry-principles-with-protractor.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use pageObjects to achieve reusable code accross your test,

Let us create a new js file for login page as `login_page.js` as below,

```
var login_page = function(){
  this.performLogin = function(){
    //add code for performing login operation.
  }
}
module.exports = new login_page();
```

Now you can import the `login_page.js` in all 'specs' and can call the `performLogin()` method whenever required.

Look at the example spec.js below,

```
describe("Test pageobject code",function(){
  var login_page = require("login_page.js");

  beforeAll(function(){
     login_page.performLogin();
   })

  it("simple test to perform after login action is performed",function()
     //do whatever you want to test 
  })
})
```